# Plotting self-made functions

Tags: plotting, functions

*EDITED AS SUGGESTED*

I have defined a function, which takes two values and returns a function n(x), like so

```
Function[d_, σ_] := 
Module[{h, ϵ0, m, e0, α, κ, β, a, ϕ, e, n},
h = 6.62606957*10^(-34);
ϵ0 = 8.8541878176*10^(-12);
m = 9.10938291*10^(-31);
e0 = 1.6*10^(-19);
α = (3/5 2^(-1/3) (3/π)^(2/3))*((ϵ0*h^2)/(m*(e0)^(5/3)))*(d^(-5/3)*σ^(-1/3));
κ = (5*α/3)*(1/2)^(2/3);
β = 4/(κ^(3/4)*Sqrt[5]);
a = 4/(β*Sinh[β/2]);
ϕ = (Cosh[β (0.5 - x)])/(β*Sinh[β/2]) - (1/β)*Coth[β/2];
e = -D[ϕ, x];
n = 0.5*D[ϕ, {x, 2}];
Return[n]]
```

Plotting n is no problem

```
Function[10^(-10), 0.01]
0.995427 Cosh[0.331805 (0.5 - x)]
```

This is n(x). It doesn't work if I use the function Function in the plot section.

```
Plot[Function[a,b],{x,0,1}]
```

and I get the message

```
0.000020428571428571424` is not a valid variable.
```

I think I understand how this happens but would like to bypass it as I don't want to copy and paste my n(x) separately every time for different values of "a" and "b". I'm a beginner, help much appreciated.

Comment: You've many  syntax errors. Please go back to the docs.

Comment: Your first and perhaps biggest problem is that `Function[a, b] = f(x)` is complete nonsense as far as _Mathematica_ is concerned. `f(x)` is equivalent to `f*x` and you can't assign to `Function[a, b]` (and you'll get an error if you try).

Comment: I apparently let myself be seriously misunderstood. I was using symbolic language. Of course I didn't define the function as seen above. In this case f(x) is come variant of the hyperbolic cosine. I just wanted to make things easier by schematically naming the x-dependant function as f(x).

Comment: The best symbolic language to use in this forum is *Mathematica* code. So, please edit your question accordingly. The error probably arises because you have `x` defined as a constant value.

Comment: Your use of Function is still not according to syntax. Please look it up in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying some of your expressions:

```
f[d_, σ_, x_] := Module[{h, ϵ0, m, e0, α, κ, β, ϕ},
 h  = 6.62606957*10^(-34);
 ϵ0 = 8.8541878176*10^(-12);
 m  = 9.10938291*10^(-31);
 e0 = 1.6*10^(-19);
 α  = (3/d/e0)^(5/3) h^2 ϵ0/(5*(2 σ)^(1/3) m Pi^(2/3));
 κ  = (5 α/3) 2^(-2/3);
 β  = 4/(κ^(3/4) Sqrt@5);
 ϕ  = Cosh[β (1/2 - x)]/(β Sinh[β/2]) - (1/β) Coth[β/2];
 D[ϕ, {x, 2}]/2]

Plot[f[10^(-10), 0.01, x] /. x -> u, {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your definition works as written. I get

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Function in Function[d_,σ_] is Protected

because `Function` is built-in syntax. Maybe you had the function called something else in your code and renamed it for posting here? If so, please don't do that; make sure the code you post actually works.

Anyway, you don't necessarily have to change your function, apart from naming it something else, like `function`. You can just do

```
Plot[function[10^(-10), 0.01], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

and it works.

The problem is that `Plot` works by substituting numerical values of `x` and evaluating the function to get the vertical coordinate. So if it sets `x = 0.002`, say, it then has to evaluate `e = -D[ϕ, 0.002]`, and `0.002` "is not a valid variable" to differentiate with respect to.

With `Evaluated -> True`, `Plot` first evaluates the expression symbolically to give `0.995427 Cosh[0.331805 (0.5 - x)]`, after which substituting a number for `x` is no problem.